# Cannot solve MySQL deadlock problem between the two terminal sessions

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, deadlock

I'm working with two MySQL terminal sessions, where I'm trying to move the number (monetary) values between the two sessions. The previous code causes deadlock issue, but I managed to successfully add only the first two values by using 'locks'.

Although I can change the first two numerical values, it is the last two (where I need to add 30 to user2_balance and add 10 to user1_balance) I am having problem with.

Below is the two MySQL terminal session I have so far, ordered from top-to-bottom:

Session 1:

```
UPDATE accounts SET balance = 100;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT balance INTO @user1_balance from accounts where id = 1;
SELECT balance INTO @user2_balance from accounts where id = 2;

SELECT @user1_balance, @user2_balance;
```

[image]

Session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES accounts read;

SELECT balance INTO @user1_balance from accounts where id = 1;
SELECT balance INTO @user2_balance from accounts where id = 2;

SELECT @user1_balance, @user2_balance;
```

Session 1:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user1_balance - 30 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

Session 1:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts;
commit;
```

[image]

Session 2:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user2_balance - 10 
WHERE id = 2;
commit;
```

[image]

Session 1: (this is where it doesn't work. 90 + 30 should be 120 but it comes out as 130.)

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user2_balance + 30
WHERE id = 2;
```

[image]

Session 2:

```
UPDATE accounts 
SET balance = @user1_balance + 10 
WHERE id = 1;
```

Session 1:

```
commit;
```

Comment: Pls add the user balances and the values in the variables at the end of each session. It is difficult to trace if cannot see what values you have there. You should also avoid explicitly locking entire tables and let innodb handle the row level locks.

Comment: @Shadow I have just added screenshot for user balances. I haven't learned innodb (sorry I'm still learning SQL) yet so I'm just on the path of learning locks.

Comment: You have not changed the values in the session variables, this is why you get incorrect results. Why don't you use atomic calculation, like `balance = balance - 10`?

Comment: What about Session 1 where Patrick becomes 130 instead of 120?

Comment: That's what I meant with the session variables not changing! `@user2_balance` remains 100 through the entire course of session 1. This got nothing to do with transactions or deadlocks.

Comment: Sorry if I can clarify..in session two, user2 balance has 90 but when i run in session one, it changes back to 100. Do you have any advice of how I can 'lock' the balance of 90 in session 1? Not sure which sql command to use...

Comment: I already told you what you should be doing...